# Parse XML from site and get values from elements

Tags: node.js, xml

I am writing a NodeJS script to get the XML from a website and get the values from a specific element.

However, when running it it says 'undefined'.

Code:

```
var http = require('http');
var xml2js = require('xml2js');

var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

var req = http.get("http://feeds.nos.nl/nosnieuwsvideo?format=xml", function(res) {
  // save the data
  var xml = '';
  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    xml += chunk;
    console.log(xml);
  });

 res.on('end', function() {
      parseString(xml, function(err, result) {
      console.log(result['title']);
      });
    });
 });

req.on('error', function(err) {
  // debug error
});
```

What's the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `result['title']`, try `result.rss.channel[0].title`

Answer (score 0):

you're using the wrong path to access it.

alternatively, you can only parse what you need

```
const transform = require('camaro')
const result = transform(xml, { title: '//channel/title'})

console.log(result.title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the answers.

I got it working by using

```
for (var i = 0; i < objects2.length; i++) {
        var title = Object.values(objects2[i].title).toString();
        title.replace("['", "").replace("']", "");

        var description = Object.values(objects2[i].description).toString();
        description.replace("['", "").replace("']", "");

        var pubtime = Object.values(objects2[i].pubDate).toString();
        pubtime.replace("['", "").replace("']", "");

        var link = Object.values(objects2[i].link).toString();
        link.replace("['", "").replace("']", "");

        console.log("\n");
        console.log(pubtime);
        console.log(link);
        console.log(title);
        console.log(description);
    }
```